# xampp apache server error 403 access forbidden on windows10

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-10

I've installed xampp in two different pc and in both of them it gives me the same error running windows10 (both with it). Apache server runs correctly, the ports are dedicated to httpd as it's supposed but when I try to access the folder of my website project to test the html files, google chrome, firefox and explorer show me a message saying: "Error 403 - access forbidden because you don't have the right permissions". I've tried everything that is in the other similar questions here and already gave permisions to all users in my folders, even to the whole drive c:. I also modified the txt files inside the folder /apache/conf/ and didn't work. I've seen that in some questions regarding the same matter, the file httpd.conf is a little bit different with parts that I can't see in mine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the problem learning some more. I post it here in case someone is starting with it like me. The point is that when you install xampp, the program has a default folder where it let's you put your projects, it's called "htdocs". So that you can work only with project folders that you create inside this "htdocs" folder. If you try to create a new folder on c:/ for example, the program will not let you access beacuase of security (everybody could access all the folders on your computer, entering your server). I hope this to be of some help for someone else. Thank you, and sorry for the newbie question.